# PHP generated XML not valid

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I am trying to get jquery to read this xml. jQuery runs the success function, but the XML is not parsed. I tried validating the xml and got Can not find declaration. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<prices>
  <pitch securityId="AUXNY" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="55970" limit_fmt_kg="55,970"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXNY" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="56000" limit_fmt_kg="56,000"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXLN" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="56020" limit_fmt_kg="56,020"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXLN" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="56260" limit_fmt_kg="56,260"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXZU" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="56150" limit_fmt_kg="56,150"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXZU" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="56390" limit_fmt_kg="56,390"/>
  </pitch>
  pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="1290" limit_fmt_kg="1,290"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="usd">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="1293" limit_fmt_kg="1,293"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXNY" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="34390" limit_fmt_kg="34,390"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXNY" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="34500" limit_fmt_kg="34,500"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXLN" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="34420" limit_fmt_kg="34,420"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXLN" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="34560" limit_fmt_kg="34,560"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXZU" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="34310" limit_fmt_kg="34,310"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXZU" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="34400" limit_fmt_kg="34,400"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="786" limit_fmt_kg="786"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="gbp">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="792" limit_fmt_kg="792"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXNY" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="39300" limit_fmt_kg="39,300"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXNY" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="39500" limit_fmt_kg="39,500"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXLN" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="39300" limit_fmt_kg="39,300"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXLN" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="39470" limit_fmt_kg="39,470"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXZU" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="39333" limit_fmt_kg="39,333"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AUXZU" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="39400" limit_fmt_kg="39,400"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="S" limit_kg="893" limit_fmt_kg="893"/>
  </pitch>
  <pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="eur">
    <price actionIndicator="B" limit_kg="908" limit_fmt_kg="908"/>
  </pitch>
</prices>
```

Comment: Did you validate the xml versus what? The doctype is not coherent with the content, for example (hint: remover the doctipe declaration and try again)

Comment: `pitch securityId="AGXLN" considerationCurrency="usd">`  You're missing a `<` on that line (roughly line 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set header response as content-type text/xml and setting dataType to xml in the jQuery ajax call.